# Fetching Transaction Details with Transaction ID Paypal Live

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am trying to fetch the transaction details with a REAL Transaction id From my Paypal account. I got the token from the CURL However, When trying to fetch it, It's returning an error.

```
100   372  100   372    0     0    477      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   478{"name":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","message":"The specified resource does not exist.","debug_id":"e077252943c9c","details":[{"issue":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","description":"Specified resource ID does not exist. Please check the resource ID and try again."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","rel":"information_link"}]}
* Connection #0 to host api-m.paypal.com left intact
```

```
curl -v -X GET https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/payments/authorizations/TRANSACTIONID \
-H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN HERE"
```

I just want to fetch the details with the ID not connecting it with any application. The transaction is a real one from my own Paypal account.

What's wrong?

Comment: If it is a transaction ID, perhaps you should be using `/captures/` not `/authorizations/`. How was this transaction created? Try creating a new one.  If it wasn't created with the REST API you may need https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1

Comment: Yeah, But still it won't let me fetch details from the Transactions happened in main account. If that's not possible, Can you instruct me on how to setup a predefined url where we can receive the transactions and fetch the details with ID? I am not creating this for a web app, It's just a simple bot where user can Confirm payments after adding their transactions ID and I can see if it's success

Answer (score 0):

Every PayPal transaction has two IDs, the receiving account's transaction ID and the payer account's transaction ID. They refer to the same PayPal transaction from either end, but they are different IDs.

It is *not* possible to do API lookups with the buyer's transaction ID, unless you have the buyer's API credentials.

If you need an ID that both accounts have in common, you should set a unique Invoice ID for the transaction during payment setup. This Invoice ID must be unique, never before used for a successful capture on the receiver account.